# Insert a large image (200px / 150px) centered in a line in a listview?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I wonder if it is possible to insert a large centered image in a listview of a jquery mobile website?

I try this:

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="d" data-divider-theme="e" style="white-space:normal"> 
    <li data-role="list-divider" role="heading" class="ui-li ui-li-divider ui-btn ui-bar-e ui-corner-top">Techno: vb.net - asp.net - vb6</li> 
    <li><img  src="/images/paris.png"/></li>
</ul>
```

But it doesn't work: ths image is rendered small.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well best I could come up with for now, maybe you can play with it, [Live Example](http://jsfiddle.net/k68Zp/6/)

```
<div data-role="page" data-theme="b" id="jqm-home"> 
    <div data-role="content">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="d" data-divider-theme="e" style="white-space:normal"> 
            <li data-role="list-divider" role="heading" class="ui-li ui-li-divider ui-btn ui-bar-e ui-corner-top">Techno: vb.net - asp.net - vb6</li> 
            <li><h3 /><p class="ui-li-aside"  style="align:center; width:200px; height:150px;"><img src="http://www.flightcentre.com.au/global-images/AIRFARE_SPECIALS_2/Paris.jpg" alt="paris"/></p></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't know why but when I copy/paste your code in my webpage the image is left aligned and small??

Comment: Paffors: ok the difference was that I used the jQuery script version 1.0a3. I replaced with 1.0a4 and now it works. Thank you.